# Algorithm to find odd word in a list of english words?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose i am having following list of words
banana,apple,orange,tree  In this list odd word is tree.Can any one give the idea to write a  algorithm.

Comment: You have to compare this with a dictionary/database/tree & see if you can find your match.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You'd need to know the context of those words, which is a problem in NLP I guess, so I don't think so there is an easy algorithm for a generic case you are presenting.

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad, it's a pretty common problem in the field of ontologies and semantic queries.

Comment: Are they any webservices ?

Answer (score 4):

What is it about `tree` that makes it the odd one out? Why not `banana` (since it's a herb, where the others are trees, and also because it's the only one in the list that doesn't end with 'e'). Or why not `orange` (since it's a colour as well as a plant, where the others are just plants).

You need to define the criteria that you're trying to filter by: something may be obvious to a human reader, but a computer algorithm can't see that without knowing all the facts that make it obvious to a human. Or at least sufficient facts that are relevant to draw a reliable conclusion.

You're basically talking about a large [knowledge-base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base), not a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is not an easy to do task, and thus my suggested solutions will be high level and include references to academic papers that aim to solve a part of your problem:

---

You can try a **semantic relatedness** approach:

- Find relatedness between every two pairs of words, filter out the word that is least related to all others.
- Semantic relatedness can be done using **[semantic sort](http://cs.technion.ac.il/news/2011/438/docs/dudu_yanay.pdf)** in a supervised learning, for example.

Another alternative is to model a **semantic representation** of each word.

- Each word will be represented by a vector representing its meaning.
  This vector can be obtained for example using the wikipedia articles
  that mention this word.  
  More information on this approach can be
  found in Markovitch et al [Wikipedia-based Semantic Interpretation
  for Natural Language Processing](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shaulm/papers/pdf/Gabrilovich-Markovitch-JAIR2009.pdf)
- After you represent your data as vectors, it is a question of finding
  the word which is least similar to the others. It can be done using
  [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning), or other alternative is choosing the point
  which is most distant from the median of all vectors.

One more possible solution is using [**WordNet**](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

---

Note that all methods are heuristics that I would try, and are expected to fail for some cases, but I believe will work pretty well for most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ontologies and reasoning algorithms. If you have an ontology that models the specific area of knowledge you will have a source of information that will allow you to distinguish words, e.g. by using the partial order and the relations and then check if the words are in the same "sub branch" of the partial order. You might even define a metric to get a "level of closeness" or something similar.

Edit: also check SPARQ, a language to query such structures. And check out triple stores which allow to get information by subject, predicate object combinations. This matches your problem since it allows you to compare two objects of your list by a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create some database of categorized words like:

```
banana {food, plant, fruit, yellow}
apple {food, plant, fruit, computer, phone}
orange {food, plant, fruit, phone}
tree {plant}
```

And then you can see that all words other than tree belong to fruit category. That kind of check would be easy to code.
Biggest problem here is getting the database - i don't think you would like to create it manually and have to idea where to find it. Also it could not work. Imagine we add

```
eclair{food, phone}
```

to this database (phone because android 2.1 is called eclair). Then for query orange, apple, banana, eclair there is two possible answers - eclair, which is not fruit or banana which is not connected with mobile phones.

Comment: ya i was having this idea...stuck in getting db